# how to wait for the android activity to fully resume after calling ZXing qr scanner

Tags: xamarin, zxing

I have an application which when starting requests a qr code from the user, and according to the qr scanned, a different fragment is loaded in the activity

I am using ZXing mobile scanner to do this

unfortunatelly the scanner returns a reply way before it shuts down and returns to the calling activity

this means that when I call the transaction code to replace the current fragment with the new one, the activity is not yet in the foreground so nothing happens

To solve this I created a ManualResetEvent (I'm using Xamarin, but I will use a Semaphore when I have to convert this to Android Studio) that I set before starting the scan , and then reset in the OnResume part of the activity

this seems to solve the problem, but it feels like there is a much better solution

Is there something I am missing?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Edit: the code I am currently using

```
public class MyActivity : Activity {
    ManualResetEvent _has_resumed = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    .....


    protected override void OnResume() {
        base.OnResume();
        _has_resumed.Set();
    }

    ......

    void scan_qr(Action<string> finished_callback) {
        #region initialize the scanner
        MobileBarcodeScanner scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
        options.UseNativeScanning = true; //use native scan
        options.AutoRotate = false;//do not rotate the screen
        options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE }; // only allow qr_codes;
        #endregion
        #region perform the actual scan, when it finishes return to the main thread and execute the callback
        _has_resumed.Reset();
        scanner.Scan(this, options) //do scan
               .ContinueWith(result => {
                   _has_resumed.WaitOne();
                   return result.Result;
               })//wait until the activity has resumed
               .ContinueWith((task_result) => { //then return the result
                   Result result = task_result.Result;
                   if (result == null) {
                       show_toast( Resource.String.questions_select_error_no_qr_scanned );
                   } else {
                       finished_callback(result.Text);
                   }
              }, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        #endregion
    }



}
```

Comment: did you search stackoverflow? It has quite few sample with QrScanner. If nothing helps please provide a project code indicating the problem.

Comment: unfortunatelly xamarin does not seem to have QrScanner imported as a component and it will probably take me way more time than I'm willing to spend to translate it, assuming ofcourse that the code is shared. my only option is ZXing I'm afraid. I'll share my code in case it helps someone in the future, but I still think there should be a better way

Comment: Can you check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281009/launching-a-qr-scanner-from-android-web-view-and-returning-the-scanned-result-us/40289859#40289859 let me know if that was not enough

Comment: yeah that will probably work, I'll just add the webview to a fragment instead of an activity and show it and when I get the result I will replace that fragment with the new one, thanks a lot mate

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do it without webview. The link was just for example but whatever works for you...